# Why does my variable not find the right date in phpmyadmin sql, but if I search it manually it does

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a list of dates(Y-m-d) stored in my database, and there's a user who fills in a DATETIME. The php function below converts the DATETIME succesfully into a DATE.

When I run the $date variable in a query it returns nothing, when I use the output (14-10-10) it does work.

```
$date = date("y-m-d", strtotime($starttime));
```

output from converted DATETIME

```
string(8) "14-10-10"
```

The query I use:

```
SELECT datum FROM `booking` WHERE datum like "14-10-10";
```

I changed the field "dates" from DATE to STRING in the database. I also tried to convert the output to different forms like an INT in 141010.

Comment: _“I changed the field "dates" from DATE to STRING in the database”_ – that’s the first thing you should _undo_ then. If you need a start and an end date, then use two DATE columns for that.

Comment: `like` without any wildcards is exactly equivalent to a plain `=` equality test. and what's `$date/14-10-10`? What is the point of that? If you had a date in the database, it's going to be `yyyy-mm-dd`, and NEVER be equal to `14-10-14/14-10-10`

Comment: What exactly do you have stored in the database? And what does the php look like? Note that if you use single quotes, variables will not get expanded.

Comment: You can't use double-quotes within a SQL query; `"` should be `'`

Comment: @Marc B I thought it would be more clear since I tried to use the variable and the output. But I removed it. I was indeed my date format. I changed it and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In database, format of date field like 'yyyy-mm-dd'

so instead of using 
$date = date("y-m-d", strtotime($starttime));
use
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($starttime));

to convert your date format

SELECT datum FROM `booking` WHERE datum="2014-10-10";